# creating objects at runtime from a config file in Java

Tags: java, android

I am writing an App for Android where I allow users to create their vehicles, which I store to a config file in a structured format. Something like:

```
[VEHICLE1]
VEHICLE1>type>car
VEHICLE1>fuelUsageMPG>30
VEHICLE1>speed>100
[ENDVEHICLE1]
[VEHICLE2]
VEHICLE2>type>car
VEHICLE2>fuelUsage>35
VEHICLE2>speed>85
[ENDVEHICLE2]
```

My App has a class named "vehicle" with the same fixed number of attributes. So what I am trying to do is to create those objects at run-time and set the object properties based on the config file so that I can then use further along in the program to perform calculations.

I parse that config file using flags and referencing groups and cycle through as many times as I find the pattern "[VEHICLE.]" but cannot figure out how to create an instance of vehicles() using VEHICLE1, VEHICLE2 or any other automated incremental object reference.

Any sample code or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should post your parsing code. As is it's difficult to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also completely agree with `Andrii` and `ElDuderino` but in case you cannot change your input format. You can try below code:

Have a method say `getVehicleList` like below:

```
public ArrayList<Vehicle> getVehicleList(File fin) {
    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

    // Taken for my convenience, you should read it from "File fin"
    InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("raw/vehicle", "raw", getPackageName()));
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String line = null;

        int cursor = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("[VEHICLE")) {
                Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
                vehicleList.add(cursor, v);
            } else if (line.contains("[ENDVEHICLE")) {
                cursor++;
            } else {
                // read vehicle attributes here
                Vehicle v1 = vehicleList.get(cursor);
                String[] attr = line.split(">");
                if (attr != null && attr.length == 3) {
                    if (attr[1].contains("type")) {
                        v1.type = attr[2];
                    } else if (attr[1].contains("fuelUsage")) {
                        v1.fuelUsageMPG = attr[2];
                    } else if (attr[1].contains("speed")) {
                        v1.speed = attr[2];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return vehicleList;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please there would be many edge cases but the idea is you have to create `ArrayList` and until you are reading the same `Vehicle` keep the `cursor` same and read getting the same `Vehicle` from `cursor` position of your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for packaging this into a comprehensive code, this helps a lot learning about the Java logic & methods to get where I need to go!

Comment: I may go down the XML path once I have a working app and I want to cleanup the coding but for now, the text file is a more simple structure to create programatically.

Comment: Please try with above approach and if it meets your expectation you could accept it. Glad if it helps you :)

Comment: thanks, I was able to incorporate it in my code, now I need to find a way to create a button with two states (up for unselected, down for selected) so I can determine which vehicle was chosen and display info based on that. It won't be for today though :)

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can simplify your your config file like this:

```
[VEHICLE1]
    type>car
    fuelUsageMPG>30
    speed>100
[ENDVEHICLE1]
[VEHICLE2]
    type>car
    fuelUsage>35
    speed>85
[ENDVEHICLE2]`
```

(but I think using a JSON or XML will be easier, as you will not have to use your own parser)

then you can just read from this file vehicle by vehicle and call a constructor of your vehicles for each of them.

Something like:
`new Vehicle(type, fuelUsage, speed)`

EDIT:

You can store them like that:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

..... loop start
al.add(new Vehicle(type, fuelUsage, speed));
..... loop end

//get the VEHICLE1
al.get(0);
//get the VEHICLE5
al.get(4);
```

Comment: I'd have put more emphasis on the "use XML or json" part...

Comment: @ElDuderino yep, I think it will be the best option

Comment: In your your proposed method, how would I reference each Vehicle instance? Can i use the proposed code repeatedly without providing some unique identifier as in a classic construction like `Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle()` ? and if so, how would I reference each instance after constructing them?

Comment: @Gaetano since I don't know what you will be doing with that `Vehicles` and I don't even know if you want to store them. But if you do need to store them - `ArrayList` will be the good option, you will be able to access them by the index using method `.get(int index)`

Comment: @ElDuderino Thanks!, I think I got it now. Let me digest and test with it. I will get back in a couple days if I am still stuck.

Comment: @AndriiLiakh what I want to do is to generate a button (or maybe a checkbox) that will allow users to select the car they want to use for a trip and display information based on the trip properties and the selected vehicle. Each user may have different types of car and any unknown number of them. Since I don't want to make them type those parameters in each time, I want to save them and re-load them as needed. If there is a better way to achieve this result, more than happy to hear your suggestions as I am not experienced with Java, I mostly wrote code in dBL(dBase) and MS Access so far...

Comment: @Gaetano you can store it using SQLite on Android